# How can i download or get at least a URL of a channel's(group) profile photo with telethon

Tags: telegram, photo, channel, telethon, group

```
import telethon
from telethon.utils import get_input_photo, get_input_chat_photo, get_input_channel
async def test(photo):
    fol = await client(get_input_chat_photo(photo))
    print(fol)
    full = await client(get_input_photo(photo))
    print(full)
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(test(257502536048270))
```

**I didn't find any library to get channel or group profile photo**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`client.download_profile_photo`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_profile_photo):

```py
# Download your own profile photo
path = await client.download_profile_photo(channel)
print(path)
```

Where `channel` is a `Channel` object, string username, or ID as long as it is in cache. The method also works with entities other than channels.